# In gnome, how do I open a terminal with the current window path?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome

In gnome, how do I open a terminal with the current window path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean Nautilus, install the package `nautilus-open-terminal` (session restart required), which will give you the option to open a terminal via the context menu.